# Why don't I plot the function according to my values? Why doesn't Excel count normally? Where did I go wrong?

Tags: excel

Why don't I plot the function according to my values? Why doesn't Excel count normally? Where did I go wrong?
in wolfram, I have one graph that should be there, and I write a function in excel, I get the wrong thing at all. tell me what's wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the formula. You need to use a different graph and increase the number of X. Plot X from -8 to 8 by 0.1 and then use a scatter plot. You will get what you seek.  The maximum step should be 0.25.

[image]

Here is -2 to 2:

[image]

And as @BigBen stated, we probably should use PI() instead of 3.14 for more accuracy:

```
=3*COS(PI()*A5)*SIN(3*PI()*A5)*SIN(PI()*A5)
```